# Bind to local IP address and use it in addpeeraddress

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, p2p

Bind local IP (Node 1)

```
bitcoind -regtest=1 -port=18333 -bind=192.168.150.110
```

Logs:

```
2021-09-01T13:14:16Z Bound to 192.168.150.110:18333
2021-09-01T13:14:16Z Bound to 127.0.0.1:18445
```

Trying to add it in peers.dat (Node 2)

```
bitcoin-cli addpeeraddress "192.168.150.110" 18333
{
  "success": false
}
```

Why does it return `false`?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks. Fixed it. Still same error. It works with `addnode` as mentioned by Sipa in deleted answer. However such manual connections do not follow `onlynet` which is the option I am experimenting with.

Comment: These two nodes are on two different computers?

Comment: Same VM. Running in two different terminals with different data directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

peers.dat (and the associated RPCs) are for the automatic connection mechanism, which includes relaying to other nodes.

You're adding an address that is not globally routable (it's a LAN IP). It cannot be inserted into the automatic connection database, because it cannot be relayed to other peers.

If you want a connection to it, use the manual connection mechanism (i.e., `addnode` RPC, or `-addnode` or `-connect` options).

Comment: (I deleted this question at first because I wasn't sure whether it wasn't due to the 83333 incorrect port you had at first)

Comment: Do you think local IPs should be allowed using `addpeeraddress` atleast for regtest? This is hidden RPC used for testing so it will be helpful.

Comment: That makes little sense in my opinion. The point of regtest is being to the extent possible identical to mainnet. Introducing differences in code between the two in order to test something would defeat the purpose.